# The Matrix of a Transformation from P2 to P1

Tags: matrices, polynomials, transformation

I don't understand how T(1), T(x), and T(x^2) were found in the picture so I did it using another method I saw on StackExchange.

(a + b)x - c => -c + (a + b)x + 0x^2 so the first row would be {0, 0, -1} (-c), second row {1, 1, 0} ( (a+b)x ) and third row {0, 0, 0,} (no x^2) but it's slightly different than the answer. What am I doing wrong or how do you calculate the way it's shown in the picture? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You find $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$ by using the definition you are given.  For example, $1=0x^2+0x+1$, i.e. $a=0$, $b=0$, $c=1$.  So, $T(1)=(a+b)x-c=(0+0)x-1=-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't replicate this for T(x) or T(x^2). So if it's T(constant) do you just put that constant value in the corresponding letter? and the basis determines which values go on top or bottom of the column?

Comment: $x=0x^2+1x+0$, i.e. $a=0, b=1, c=0$.  So $T(x)=(0+1)x-0=x$.

Comment: Then with that method, why would T(x^2) not be equal to x^2? Although there is no x^2 in the definition, I don't see how it equals x?

Comment: The definition is: (a + b)x - c => -c + (a + b)x + 0x^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your method and the given solution is that you have ordered your basis $\{x^2,x,1\}$, but the problem tells you to order it $\{1,x,x^2\}$.